# Multithreaded Exclusive Access To Files

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, pthreads

I have a program that has two threads running at the same time (main thread and one pthread). This program manages a cache of files on a local folder. The threads do the following tasks:

- Thread 0 can read from and download files into the cache;
- Thread 1 can read from and write into files in the cache.

This means that I need to assure exclusive access to each of the files within the cache. Problem is, I don't know how to do it!

Creating a mutex for each of the files inside the cache will obviously work, but the sheer number of files makes this option prohibitive. Using flockfile and funlockfile seems like my best bet, but won't using these functions force me into having file descriptors for each of the files in the cache? That is to say, won't it be necessary for me to first fopen all of the files inside the cache and then keep the resulting file descriptors in a buffer accessible by the two threads?

Answer (score 2):

To access the files you need to open them anyway.

The calls to `flockfile()` and `funlockfile()` only need to be placed "around" the calls doing I/O on the files.

Answer (score 2):

The cache could simply download the file to a different name, like `file.partial`, and when it's done, it can atomically rename it to `file`. The consumer would only ever look for `file` and thus never see a partial file.